# Issue with adding numbers to an array element and assigning to another array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my code below, in the line ipClassRangeTop[3] = ipClassRangeBottom[3] + subNetCount - 1; it seems that the subNetCount is also added to the ipClassRangeBottom[3] as well.  This is not the result I was expecting.  I just want the ipClassRangeTop[3] to have that value.

Could someone people let me know what I may be doing wrong.  I am very new to any type of coding so any help would be very appreciated.

```
var ipAddress = "172.16.1.1";
var subNetCount = 1 << 6;
var ipClassRangeTop = new Array();
var ipClassRangeBottom = new Array();
var classMaskDec = 65536;
var loopCount = 3; //classMaskDec/subNetCount;

//console.log(ipAddress, "ip address");
ipAddress = ipAddress.split(".");
ipClassRangeBottom = ipAddress;
ipClassRangeBottom[2] = 0;
ipClassRangeBottom[3] = 0;
ipClassRangeTop = ipClassRangeBottom;
//console.log(ipAddress, "ip address");

while (loopCount > 0 ) {
//console.log(i++);
console.log(ipClassRangeBottom, "1st bottom in loop");

ipClassRangeTop[3] = ipClassRangeBottom[3] + subNetCount - 1;
console.log(ipClassRangeBottom, "after top [3] assign");

if (ipClassRangeTop[3] > 255) {
    ipClassRangeTop[2] = ipClassRangeTop[2] + 1;
    ipClassRangeTop[3] = subNetCount - 1;
    console.log("IF RAN");
}

console.log(loopCount);
console.log(ipClassRangeTop);
console.log(ipClassRangeBottom);

ipClassRangeBottom[3] = ipClassRangeBottom[3] + subNetCount;
console.log(ipClassRangeBottom);
loopCount--;
}

console.log(ipAddress, "ip address");
console.log(ipClassRangeTop);
console.log(ipClassRangeBottom);
```

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a reference to an array from one variable to another does not make a copy of the array (in JavaScript).  That is:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a;
b[0] = "Hello World!";
alert(a[0]); // alerts "Hello World!"
```

If you want to make a real copy of an array:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.slice(0);
b[0] = "Hello World!";
alert(a[0]); // alerts "1"
```